# matches.find() with replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Java and I found a loop in existing code that seems like it should be an infinite loop (or otherwise have highly undesirable behavior) which actually works.

Can you explain what I'm missing? The reason I think it should be infinite is that according to the documentation here (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) a call to replaceAll will reset the matcher (*This method first resets this matcher. It then scans the input sequence...*). So I thought the below code would do its replacement and then call find() again, which would start over at the beginning. And it would keep finding the same string, since as you can see the string is just getting wrapped in a tag.

In case it's not obvious, Pattern and Matcher are the classes in java.util.regex.

```
String aTagName = getSomeTagName()
String text = getSomeText()
Pattern pattern = getSomePattern()
Matcher matches = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matches.find()) {
    text = matches.replaceAll(String.format("<%1$s> %2$s </%1$s>", aTagName, matches.group()));
}
```

Why is that not the case?

Comment: Nupe. Because you are replacing the match, so it won't exist anymore... I think... I don't know. It's late and I'm tired and thus unreasonable. Lemme summon Uni.

Comment: Also curious may be while loop is not even needed, as replaceAll will do the work in one go and resets the matches. I think a simple if would work fine in this case. If thats the case I don't know why you need to check matches.find, a simple replace all should work.

Answer (score 2):

I share your suspicions that this code very likely is unintended, for `replaceAll` changes the state, and since it scans the string to replace, the result is that **only 1 search** is performed and **stated group is used to replace all searches with this group**.

```
String text = "abcdEfg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
Matcher matches = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matches.find()) {
    System.out.println(text); // abcdEfg
    text = matches.replaceAll(matches.group());
    System.out.println(text); // aaaaEaa
}
```

As `replaceAll` tells the matcher to scan through the string, it ends up moving the pointer to the end to exhaust the entire string's state. Then `find` resumes search (from the current state - which is the end, not the start), but the search has already been exhausted.

---

One of the correct ways to iterate and replace for each group appropriately may be to use `appendReplacement`:

```
String text = "abcdEfg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
Matcher matches = pattern.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matches.find()) {
    matches.appendReplacement(sb, matches.group().toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(text); // some of ABCDEFG
}
matches.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb); // ABCDEFG
```

Answer (score 1):

The below examples shows there is no reason to call the while loop if you are using replace all. In both the cases the answer is

**is**  th **is**  a summer ? Th **is**   **is**  very hot summer.  **is** n't it?

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "is this a summer ? This is very hot summer. isn't it?";
        String tag = "b";
        String pattern = "is";
        System.out.println(question(text,tag,pattern));
        System.out.println(alt(text,tag,pattern));
    }

    public static String question(String text, String tag, String p) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher matcher= pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            text = matcher.replaceAll(
                String.format("<%1$s> %2$s </%1$s>",
                tag, matcher.group()));
        }
        return text;
    }

    public static String alt(String text, String tag, String p) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher matcher= pattern.matcher(text);
        if(matcher.find())
            return matcher.replaceAll(
                String.format("<%1$s> %2$s </%1$s>",
                tag, matcher.group()));
        else
            return text;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't go into an infinite loop, though? I would think since matcher.replaceAll() is resetting the matches, that matcher.find() is always starting again from the start so the while condition would never be false.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I guess the answer is in the other answer: "Then find resumes search (from the current state - which is the end, not the start), but the search has already been exhausted."